# Flutter, doble consulta Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-auth

Tengo un proyecto en Flutter con Firebase, que cada vez que accede un usuario se carga su informacion, tal como sucursal, turno, nombre, etc.

Entre esta informacion del usuario tengo la de "Acceso" que es booleano para definir si puede entrar o no; cambia ante cada cambio de estatus (autolistener)

El problema sí tiene Acceso: false y cierro sesión, antes de volver a iniciar sesión cambio su Acceso: true, cuando inicia sesión imprime repetido la informacion de la siguiente manera:

```
I/flutter (12996): acceso: false 
I/flutter (12996): sin acceso
I/flutter (12996): acceso: true
I/flutter (12996): con acceso
```

**¿Como evito la primera llamada incorrecta?**

```
FireUsuario({String userId, Auth auth, VoidCallback logoutCallback}) {
//Consulta tiempo real
Firestore.instance
    .collection("Administradores")
    .document(userId)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
    if (documentSnapshot.data.containsKey("Acceso")) {
      // obtener preferencias compartidas

      print("acceso: " + documentSnapshot.data["Acceso"].toString());

      if (documentSnapshot.data["Acceso"]) {
        print("con acceso");
      } else {
        print("sin acceso");

      }
    }
  }
});
}
```

Comment: supongo que usas Firebase Auth + Firestore, si cierras sesión también tendrias que marcar el acceso false en Firestore

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso autentico con Firebase tambien y siempre pasa que recibo inicios falsos.
Desde que salio la nueva version de Firebase lo inicializo y espero la conexión, mientras eso no ocurra muestro una pantalla de Loading y esos errores al inicio no ocurren mas.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        // Initialize FlutterFire
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              //Si se conecta
          } else {
              return MaterialApp(
            home: Loading(),
          );
        }
```